# Imported meshes look faceted

Tags: edit-mode, import

I have bought a few files from turbo squid, unfortunately for my needs some of the files look faceted.

Generally I will import them as OBJs.

I have tried using the the smooth and relax tool, but they don't help enough. I want to really add more nodes/vertices - at least i think that's what i want to do.

I have only ever used CAD programs before so Blender is completely new, if anyone could point me to the tool name or a tutorial I would appreciate it

[image]

Comment: Looks like that particular piece just doesn't have smooth shading applied.

Comment: Use smooth shading and a subsurf modifier.

Comment: Some imported object may contain "**Sharp Edges**" setting, you might need to clean it up in edit mode

Comment: I will be exporting this to use in a webGL application, so just chaning the shading is not sufficient, I want to actually change the model to be smoother. What is the tool required it edit mode to do such operations?